# Where can I find my favorites mobile?

Tags: feature-request, android-app

I tagged favorites on my PC and want to have a look at them on my phone...

I don't want to search them again!

Comment: You can switch to desktop site anytime

Comment: you mean in the browser? - yes but its not very comfortable... you know?

Comment: I'm afraid it is the only solution.

Comment: ok thx - I wrote it here, because is written in the "help" section to make a post here...

Comment: yes, sorry - thx